# SQL Query Help - Wont run because of Average_Fee

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I cant get this query to run and I am not sure what to do to fix it? Wont run because of Average_Fee.

```
SELECT LENGTH, AVG(RENTAL_FEE) AVERAGE_FEE
FROM MARINA_SLIP
WHERE AVERAGE_FEE < 3500
GROUP BY LENGTH
ORDER BY LENGTH DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You need to assign an alias to `avg(rental_fee)` using `AS` clause whenever using a function in `SELECT` list.</strike>

You can not reference to alias inside the same block. Also, `where` for aggregate function is done by using `having` clause - it's applied to your `group`.

```
SELECT LENGTH, AVG(RENTAL_FEE) AS AVERAGE_FEE 
FROM MARINA_SLIP 
GROUP BY LENGTH 
HAVING AVG(RENTAL_FEE) < 3500
ORDER BY LENGTH DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your repley. I Have tried that, but still get the an error.  ORA-00904: "AVERAGE_FEE": invalid identifier

Comment: I'm sorry. You are right. The error lies somewhere else. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the having clause for aggregated values

```
SELECT LENGTH, AVG(RENTAL_FEE) AVERAGE_FEE
FROM MARINA_SLIP
GROUP BY LENGTH
HAVING AVERAGE_FEE < 3500
ORDER BY LENGTH DESC;
```